# Probability space in the Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose I have a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and a random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Consider a random sample $\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ of independent random variables with the same distribution as $X$. I was told that  $X_i:\Omega^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $X_i(\omega)=X(\omega_i)$.

Then, in the law of large numbers, $$(X_1+\cdots+X_n)/n\rightarrow E[X],$$
does the domain of each term of the sequence changes? In the definition of almost sure convergence the domain is fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your objection is correct. The way to get around is by Kolmogorov extension: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem

It is an essentially unique way to make the product space $\hat{\Omega}=\prod_{i\in {\Bbb N}} \Omega$ into a probability space in which the $\sigma$-algebra is generated by sets of the form:
 $$ \hat{A} = A_1 \times \cdots \times A_n \times \prod_{k>n} \Omega $$
and the probability of such an element is given by:
 $$ P(\hat{A}) = P(A_1) \times \cdots \times P(A_n).$$
An issue is an infinite sequence $\omega=(\omega_i)_{i\geq 1}$ and your observable sequence becomes $X_i(\omega)=\omega_i$. The projection onto the first $n$ factors will correspond to the space $\Omega^n$ with the standard product measure.

Comment: So, in conclusion, I can find a new probability space $(\hat{\Omega},\hat{\mathcal{F}},\hat{P})$ where every $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ is defined, right?

Comment: Indeed, that's the main point of Kolmogorov. There is a 'nice' fixed space on which all the random variables are defined. And when restricting to a finite number you get the distribution you would expect for that finite number of variables.

Comment: And due to difficulty, this is often omitted in many standard textbook? I took me whole day and until I see this discussion, I understand why they do not mention the probability space.